# Why will my build_heap method not stop running?

Tags: python, heap, interrupt

I have written a class for a `MinHeap` class and created a `build_heap` method. Whenever I call the `build_heap` function the program continues to run unless I keyboard interrupt it. The heap appears to built when I interrupt the function call, but I am curious as to why the function appears to be running infinitely.

MinHeap Class:

```
class MinHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap_list = [0]
        self.current_size = 0

    def perc_up(self, index):
        while index // 2 > 0:
            if self.heap_list[index] < self.heap_list[index // 2]:
                temp = self.heap_list[index // 2]
                self.heap_list[index // 2] = self.heap_list[index]
                self.heap_list[index] = temp
            index = index // 2

    def perc_down(self, index):
        while (index * 2) <= self.current_size:
            mc = self.min_child(index)
            if self.heap_list[index] > self.heap_list[mc]:
                temp = self.heap_list[index]
                self.heap_list[index] = self.heap_list[mc]
                self.heap_list[mc] = temp
            i = mc

    def min_child(self, index):
        if (index * 2 + 1) > self.current_size:
            return index * 2
        else:
            if self.heap_list[index * 2] < self.heap_list[index * 2 + 1]:
                return index * 2
            else:
                return index * 2 + 1

    def insert(self, value):
        self.heap_list.append(value)
        self.current_size += 1
        self.perc_up(self.current_size)

    def peek(self):
        return self.heap_list[1]

    def del_min(self):
        ret_val = self.heap_list[1]
        self.heap_list[1] = self.heap_list[self.current_size]
        self.heap_list.pop()
        self.perc_down(1)
        return ret_val

    def is_empty(self):
        if self.current_size == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def size(self):
        return self.current_size

    def build_heap(self, a_list):
        i = len(a_list) // 2
        self.current_size = len(a_list)
        self.heap_list = [0] + a_list[:]
        while (i > 0):
            self.perc_down(i)
            i = i - 1
```

Output when calling build_heap:

```
>>> heap = MinHeap()
>>> lyst = [ 1, 3, 6, 19, 13, 4, 2]
>>> heap.build_heap(lyst)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    heap.build_heap(lyst)
  File "C:/Users/frost_000/Documents/Python Files/MinHeap.py", line 62, in         build_heap
self.perc_down(i)
  File "C:/Users/frost_000/Documents/Python Files/MinHeap.py", line 16, in  perc_down
    while (index * 2) <= self.current_size:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

```python
>>> heap.heap_list
>>> [0, 1, 3, 2, 19, 13, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Not the answer, but delete the 'i = mc' line in perc_down. i isn't used anywhere else in that scope, so at best it's a redundant line.

Comment: You're probably getting stuck in perc_down(). I don't see anywhere where you're decrementing self.current_size, so you'll stay in that while loop.

Comment: `while (index * 2) <= self.current_size:` -> `current_size` is not updated in this loop -> infinite loop.

Comment: Was `i` supposed to be `index`?

Comment: `i = mc` what is `i`? don't you mean `index = mc`?

Comment: The problem, as others have pointed out, is that you need to modify the `index` value somewhere in the loop. Those who commented that you need to modify `current_size` in that loop are wrong. However, in your `del_min` function, you *do* need to decrement `current_size` after you remove the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `perc_down()` never returns when `build_help()` call it. This is because the condition `(index * 2) <= self.current_size` never changes and is always `True` because it's not affected by any of the statements within the `while` loop.

With the change and addition shown, it seems to now work:

```
class MinHeap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap_list = [0]
        self.current_size = 0

    def perc_up(self, index):
        while index // 2 > 0:
            if self.heap_list[index] < self.heap_list[index // 2]:
                temp = self.heap_list[index // 2]
                self.heap_list[index // 2] = self.heap_list[index]
                self.heap_list[index] = temp
            index = index // 2

    def perc_down(self, index):
        while (index * 2) <= self.current_size:
            mc = self.min_child(index)
            if self.heap_list[index] > self.heap_list[mc]:
                temp = self.heap_list[index]
                self.heap_list[index] = self.heap_list[mc]
                self.heap_list[mc] = temp
            index = mc  #### changed

    def min_child(self, index):
        if (index * 2 + 1) > self.current_size:
            return index * 2
        else:
            if self.heap_list[index * 2] < self.heap_list[index * 2 + 1]:
                return index * 2
            else:
                return index * 2 + 1

    def insert(self, value):
        self.heap_list.append(value)
        self.current_size += 1
        self.perc_up(self.current_size)

    def peek(self):
        return self.heap_list[1]

    def del_min(self):
        ret_val = self.heap_list[1]
        self.heap_list[1] = self.heap_list[self.current_size]
        self.heap_list.pop()
        self.current_size -= 1  #### added
        self.perc_down(1)
        return ret_val

    def is_empty(self):
        if self.current_size == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def size(self):
        return self.current_size

    def build_heap(self, a_list):
        i = len(a_list) // 2
        self.current_size = len(a_list)
        self.heap_list = [0] + a_list[:]
        while (i > 0):
            print('i: {}'.format(i))
            self.perc_down(i)
            i = i - 1

heap = MinHeap()
lyst = [ 1, 3, 6, 19, 13, 4, 2]
heap.build_heap(lyst)
```

Comment: This is the mistake. Thank you for the help! Spent too long staring at it and overlooked that typo probably one hundred times.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't overlook the line also added to the `del_min()` method — even though that wasn't the cause of the infinite loop.